# MySQL one table or more for different products types?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I sell on my site games, songs or albums. Only in terms of performance, is it better to have only one table with field 'type' or one table per type? The fields are pretty much the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Only in terms of performance? Probably the first option. But the first option would appear to win out anyway, right?

Comment: You "sell" games songs or albums, meaning?? that you want 1 search method throug all 3 things i would go for the type field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on how many records you're expecting to have, and what kind of queries you intend of running. If you're going to be looking at millions of each type, then it might be more performant to split them into separate tables, but if you add indexes to the right columns it would be absolutely fine to have a single table.

For simplicity a single table is nice - You can simply filter the type of item you want with the type column. Just make sure you index that column, otherwise it'll be really bad when it comes to performance once you start getting a lot of records. But without knowing how many items you think there will be in the long run it's quite a difficult thing to estimate.

Maybe someone with more DBA knowledge can chime in here, but I'd say

- If you want the absolute best possible performance - split the tables
- If you don't mind what will probably be milliseconds difference - single table.

As @Sander Visser has noted, if you wanted to be able to do a full text search through all of your items for sale, a single table would be much better. Trying to do this over 3 tables would be a little trickier as you'd most likely end up with 3 separate queries (or unioned queries) which would likely be slower than a single table search.

Given that you'd be looking at very small time differences between a 1 table and 3 table implementation on normal operations, I'd recommend a single table approach.

Comment: Not bad for 6 minutes. But I disagree with the summary.

Comment: If you want to do full text searchs throug the games/songs/albums splitting the tables doesn't necessarily mean better performance

Comment: Agreed. More information in the question would certainly help determine whether this would be needed or not though.

Comment: Why not provide some hard science otherwise this is starting to sound like idle speculation. (I think idle speculation is fine for comments BTW ;-) )

Comment: ha yeah probably should, but I don't have any hard science :( That's why I've invited someone with a lot of DBA knowledge to chime in :D

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if your concerns are performance vs simplicity, you don't have to choose. You can have advantages of both using partitions:

- Use single table for simpler queries
- Partition it using your (enum) type field, so that queries for specific type will search only relevant data.

This is from [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html):

> Some queries can be greatly optimized in virtue of the fact that data satisfying a given WHERE clause can be stored only on one or more partitions, which automatically excludes any remaining partitions from the search.

In your case, providing you have 3 types, you can  define partitioning as like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
    ...
    type INT NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY HASH( type ) PARTITIONS 3;
```

See example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52156/mysql-add-index-to-low-cardinality-text-column)